# Why camel routes start and stops on its own?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, jboss-esb

My jar is deployed in jboss fuse server, i have installed it using osgi command. But DefaultShutdownStrategy does gracefull shutdown of my camel routes and again my routes starts and then againg gets shutdown, how should i find whats wrong with my camel route?

```
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: DLC_Error_Handler shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://DLCErrorHandler]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountResp]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountRequest shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountReq]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCRMResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCRMRequest]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: SendCRMResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://sendResponse]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: CreateAccountContract shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://createAccountContract]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetNonRecCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getNonRecCharges]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRateClassList shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRateClassList]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: getRecCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRecCharges]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetBillingCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getBillingCharges]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRatePlan shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRatePlanDetails]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | 4 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: MainRoute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[activemq://queue:createAccountContract]
16:23:46,095 | INFO  | Thread-358       | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Graceful shutdown of 12 routes completed in 4 seconds
16:23:50,742 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: MainRoute started and consuming from: Endpoint[activemq://queue:createAccountContract]
16:23:50,743 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRatePlan started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRatePlanDetails]
16:23:50,743 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetBillingCharges started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getBillingCharges]
16:23:50,743 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: getRecCharges started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRecCharges]
16:23:50,744 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRateClassList started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRateClassList]
16:23:50,744 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetNonRecCharges started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getNonRecCharges]
16:23:50,744 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: CreateAccountContract started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://createAccountContract]
16:23:50,745 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: SendCRMResponse started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://sendResponse]
16:23:50,745 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCRMResponse started and consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCRMRequest]
16:23:50,747 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountRequest started and consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountReq]
16:23:50,747 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountResponse started and consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountResp]
16:23:50,748 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: DLC_Error_Handler started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://DLCErrorHandler]
16:23:50,748 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Total 12 routes, of which 12 are started.
16:23:50,748 | INFO  | rint Extender: 1 | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Apache Camel 2.17.0.redhat-630187 (CamelContext: camel-85) started in 4.572 seconds
16:23:50,752 | INFO  | Thread-360       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Apache Camel 2.17.0.redhat-630187 (CamelContext: camel-85) is shutting down
16:23:50,753 | INFO  | Thread-360       | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Starting to graceful shutdown 12 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
16:23:53,186 | INFO  | qtp1920375558-80 | route1                           | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Create Account Contract Request received : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>n  | <CreateAccountContractRequest>n  |     <CAF_No>CAF_31883</CAF_No>n  |     <CAN_No>9165199</CAN_No>n  |     <CreateAccountContractDetails>n  |         <subsNo>17954</subsNo>n  |         <ratePlanID>ENT_BIA100</ratePlanID>n  |         <servicegroupno>15452</servicegroupno>n  |         <startDate>2017-10-08T00:00:00+05:30</startDate>n  |         <RCAmount>75000.0</RCAmount>n  |         <NRCAmount>25000.0</NRCAmount>n  |     </CreateAccountContractDetails>n  |     <SessionObject>n  |         <ipAddress>10.158.103.4</ipAddress>n  |         <userName>admin</userName>n  |         <usrNo>1</usrNo>n  |     </SessionObject>n  | </CreateAccountContractRequest>n  | 
16:23:53,231 | INFO  | qtp1920375558-80 | route1                           | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | send request onto the queue
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: DLC_Error_Handler shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://DLCErrorHandler]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountResp]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCreateAccountRequest shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCreateAccountReq]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: LogCRMResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://logCRMRequest]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: SendCRMResponse shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://sendResponse]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: CreateAccountContract shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://createAccountContract]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetNonRecCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getNonRecCharges]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRateClassList shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRateClassList]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: getRecCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRecCharges]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetBillingCharges shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getBillingCharges]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: GetRatePlan shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[direct://getRatePlanDetails]
16:23:54,793 | INFO  | 9 - ShutdownTask | DefaultShutdownStrategy          | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Route: MainRoute shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[activemq://queue:createAccountContract]
```

Comment: You can use the Red Hat Customer Portal to get faster support for JBoss Fuse

Comment: Thanks, have posted it there!

Comment: Which Fuse Version you using? What is camel-version?

Comment: I am using fuse 6.3 and camel 2.15.1